# Creating PDF from Word doc via Powershell - ExportasFixedFormat throws "File is in use" error

Tags: powershell, pdf, ms-word, adobe

I am using the following code to create a PDF document from a Word 2010 doc, after "SaveAs" starting being glitchy** after months of the code being utilized daily.

```
     ....
     $doc.SaveAs([ref]$docName,  [ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocumentDefault) 
     $doc.close()
     $word.Quit([ref]0)
     [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word) | out-null
     [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($doc) | out-null

     $wordPDF = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
     $savePDF = $wordPDF.Documents.Open($docName, $false, $false)
     $savePDF.exportAsFixedFormat($pdfname, 17)
```

The PDF is created as an empty(?) file, and I receive this error:

```
Exception calling "ExportAsFixedFormat" with "15" argument(s): "This file is in use by another application or user."
At A:\yadayada.ps1:340 char:38
+          $savePDF.exportAsFixedFormat <<<< ($pdfName,17)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

I have tried defining all arguments, deleting the old PDF document, and basically anything else the Internet has suggested thus far. Hence my creation of my first StackOverflow question  :)

I found [this warning](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/pdf-error-1015-11001-update.html) from Adobe, but do not know how to circumvent it using Powershell, ExportasFixedFormat or SaveAs.

Thank you for your help!

** Glitchy = throwing this error inconsistently, despite all files and variables remaining the same: 
    `Exception calling "SaveAs" with "16" argument(s): "Command failed"
At A:\yadayada.ps1:339 char:25
+          $savePDF.SaveAs <<<< ([ref]$pdfName, [ref]17)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException`

---

UPDATE: Here is the entire chunk of code

```
### Error handling & Functions  ##########################################
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"  
$dateTime = get-date -f "yyyyMMdd_Hmmss"
$scriptHome = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path # where am I?
$fileHome = $scriptHome + "\"                         # set HOME location (parent file)                              
# $fileHome = "\\homedrive\"
function replaceText ($findTxt, $replaceTxt) {                          
$Word.Selection.Find.Execute($findTxt, $True, $True, $False, $False,    
    $False, $True, 1, $False, $replaceTxt)}                             
Function write-all {
   Param ([string]$logString)
   Add-content $logFile -value $logString
   write-host $logString }
Function write-log {
   Param ([string]$logString)
   Add-content $logFile -value $logString }


#-- START BASIC EDITING HERE  --------------------------------------------
##########################################################################
##                                                                      ##
##  $product and $toName are used in the file paths, so please confirm  ##
##  their accuracy before you open the CMD file.                        ##
##                                                                      ##
##  $toTemplate is the name of the current turnover notification        ##
##  document. Ideally this will remain somewhat consistent based on     ##
##  the product and/or turnover name so it does not need to be edited   ##
##  for every turnover.                                                 ##
##                                                                      ##
##  $toPath is the complete file path where the turnover documents      ##
##  will be saved for each client. This should not change often.        ##
##                                                                      ##
##  $toDocName will be  the file name for the merged turnover document  ##
##  for each firm. Ideally this will remain consistent as well.         ##
##                                                                      ##
##  Once the script is complete, $toTemplate will be merged with        ##
##  $contactFile to create files for each firm, which are saved as      ##
##  firm\product\toName\toDocName.docx (and toDocName.pdf).             ##   
##                                                                      ##
##########################################################################
[console]::ForegroundColor = "green"
$productNames = ("A","B","C")
$product = read-host "Product (A/B/C) " 
while ($productNames -notcontains $product) { 
    [console]::ForegroundColor = "red"
    $product = read-host "Product name is incorrect. Please re-enter"   
}
[console]::ForegroundColor = "green"
$toName  = read-host "Document name (e.g., Customer Notification of Turnovers - 20149999) " 
[console]::ResetColor()
$toTemplate = "Template.docx" 
$toPath = $product + "\Notifications\" 
$toDocName = "Notification - " + $toName 
#-- END BASIC EDITING ----------------------------------------------------

##########################################################################
##                                                                      ## 
##  Begin writing log information in Notifications\Product\Logs         ##
##  write-all will write to the screen and log. write-log only writes   ## 
##  to the log.                                                         ##
##                                                                      ##
##########################################################################
$logPath = $fileHome + $product + "\logs\"
if (!(Test-Path -path "$logPath")) { 
    New-Item "$logPath" -type directory | out-null
}
$logFile = $logPath + $toName + "-" + $dateTime + ".log"
New-Item "$logFile" -type file | out-null
write-host "`n"
write-all "******************************************************************************"
write-all "*                     PROCESS INFORMATION                                    *"
write-all "******************************************************************************"
write-host " - Home Directory: $fileHome `n"
write-log "Home Directory: $fileHome"
write-log "Product: $product "
write-log "Name: $toName"
write-log "Template: $toTemplate"

##########################################################################
##                                                                      ##
##  $TODAY replaces "DATE" in the template document. Currently the      ##
##  format is "Monday, January 1, 1900." Get-date customization is      ##
##  found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx   ##
##                                                                      ##
##  if you would like to manually enter a date, put a '#' in front of   ##
##  'get-date' and delete the '#' in front of the next line.            ##
##                                                                      ##
##########################################################################
$TODAY = get-date -f "dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy"   
# $TODAY = "January 1, 1900"

##########################################################################
##                                                                      ##
##  This section sets the file locations for the template document,     ##
##  contacts document and all files and directories created by the      ##
##  script. The script sets the file locations based on its location.   ##
##  Thus, any changes in locations or names need to be reflected here.  ##
##                                                                      ##
##########################################################################
$toTemplate  = $fileHome + $product + "\" + $toTemplate                # set template document's full path 
$contactFile = $fileHome + $product + "\" + "Contacts.csv"             # set CSV file name and location     
write-log "Template Name: $toTemplate"
write-log "Contact file: $contactFile"

##########################################################################
##                                                                      ##
##  This section checks the CSV file for blanks and trailing spaces.    ##
##  Firm names with trailing spaces in toReceive will be imported so    ##
##  the user can be alerted to the spaces. Otherwise, the script would  ##
##  not import that line because toReceive is not equal to 'Y'.         ##
##                                                                      ##
##########################################################################
# import rows from the contact CSV file where the toReceive field has a 'Y'. 
$importCSV   = import-csv $contactFile | Where-Object { $_.toReceive -eq 'Y' -or $_.toReceive -eq 'Y '} 
if ($importCSV -ne $null) {
    $rowNum = 1  # accounts for header row
    foreach ($row in $importCSV) {
     $firmSpace = $row.firmName    # saves firm name as a string for trailing space removal
     $firm = $firmSpace.TrimEnd()  # removes any trailing spaces

     # If the toReceive column has trailing spaces, script will terminate.
     if ($row.toReceive -ne 'Y') {
        write-all "Please check $firm's toReceive column for trailing spaces."
        exit
     } 

     # If a firm name or primary contact name is blank, script will terminate.
     $rowNum = $rowNum + 1
     if ($row.firmName -eq [DBNull]::Value -or $row.firmName -eq "") { 
        write-all "Firm name is blank in row $rowNum.  Please correct and reprocess script." -foregroundcolor "magenta"
        exit
        }

     # If a firm name has a trailing space, script will terminate.
     if ($firm.length -ne $firmSpace.length) { 
        write-all "Please check $firm's firmName column for trailing spaces." -foregroundcolor "magenta"
        exit
        }   

     # If a folder name has a trailing space, script will terminate.
     if ($row.folderName -ne "") {
        $folderSpace = $row.folderName
        $folder = $folderSpace.TrimEnd()
        if ($folder.length -ne $folderSpace.length) {
        write-all "Please check $firm's folderName column for trailing spaces." -foregroundcolor "magenta"
        exit
        }
     }
     # If firm's Primary Contact is blank, script will terminate.
     if ($row.primaryContact -eq [DBNull]::Value -or $row.primaryContact -eq "") { 
        write-all "Primary contact is blank for $firm. Please correct and reprocess script." -foregroundcolor "magenta"
        exit
     }
    }    
    $rowCount = @($importCSV).count
    write-host " - $toTemplate will be merged with contacts from $rowCount firms from the $product Contacts file. `n" 
    write-log   "Contact file rows: $rowCount" 
    write-host " - Notification documents will be saved to $toPath$toDocName `n"
    $processFiles = read-host "Continue? (Y/N)"
    while ($processFiles -ne "Y" -and $processFiles -ne "N") {
    $processFiles = read-host "Please enter Y or N"
    }
    if ($processFiles -ne "Y") { 
    write-log "Script terminated by user. No files were processed or created because user selected not to continue."
    write-host "Script will terminate. No files were processed or created."
    exit 
    }
    ##########################################################################
    ##                                                                      ##
    ##  This section starts looping through the contactFile data. It will:  ##
    ##       1. open the current TO document ($toTemplate)                  ##
    ##       2. replace CONTACT with the firm contact name(s)               ## 
    ##       3. replace DATE with $TODAY                                    ##
    ##       4. replace TONAME with $toName                                 ##
    ##       5. fill in the CC info, if available                           ##
    ##  This section needs some additional code to catch poorly formatted   ##
    ##  contacts documents.                                                 ##
    ##                                                                      ##
    ##########################################################################
    ###############  for each client in the CSV file  ########################
    write-log ""
    write-log "*******************************************************************************"
    write-log "*                    PROCESSING NOTIFICATIONS                                 *"
    write-log "*******************************************************************************"  
    foreach ($row in $importCSV) {
     $firm = $row.firmName   # sets the current row's firm name (for use in file names)
     if ($row.folderName -eq [DBNull]::Value -or $row.folderName -eq "") {
        $folder = $firm
     }
     else { $folder = $row.folderName }
     write-all ""
     write-all ""
     write-all "************************** Processing: $firm  ****************************"
     write-all ""      

     if ($row.primaryContact -ne [DBNull]::Value -or $row.primaryContact -ne "") {  #if primaryContact is not empty, carry on.
        if ($row.secondContact -ne [DBNull]::Value) {   # if there is a secondary contact
          if ($row.thirdContact -ne [DBNull]::Value) {  # if there is a third contact
             $contact = $row.primaryContact + ", " + $row.secondContact + ", and " + $row.thirdContact  #concatenate all contacts
         # need to add code to catch if an email address is blank -- currently only set for primary contact
         $contactEmail =  $row.primaryEmail + "; " + $row.secondEmail + "; " + $row.thirdEmail      #concatenate contact email addresses
         write-all "Three contacts detected for $firm."
          }
          else { 
        $contact = $row.primaryContact + " and " + $row.secondContact   # no third contact - concatenate 1 & 2
        # need to add code to catch if an email address is blank -- currently only set for primary contact
        $contactEmail = $row.primaryEmail + "; " + $row.secondEmail     # concatenate contact email addresses
        write-all "Two contacts detected for $firm."
          }
        }  
        else {   # does not catch if there is a third contact but not a second
        $contact = $row.primaryContact  # only a primary contact is listed
            if ($row.primaryEmail -eq [DBNull]::Value -or $row.primaryEmail -eq "") {  # if primaryContact email is blank, carry on.
            $contactEmail = "No email address provided for " + $row.primaryContact 
            write-all "The email for address for $row.primaryContact at $firm is blank. Script will continue." -foregroundcolor "magenta"
        }
        else { $contactEmail = $row.primaryEmail }
        write-all "One contact detected for $firm."
        } 
       }   
     else {
        write-all "Primary Contact is blank for $firm. Please correct and reprocess script." -foregroundcolor "magenta"
        exit
     }

     ##########################################################################
     ##                                                                      ##
     ##  This section contains the path where the firm's turnover documents  ##
     ##  will be saved ($DirectoryToSaveTo), as well as the formatting for   ##
     ##  PDF and DOCX file names ($pdfName and $docName).                    ##
     ##                                                                      ##
     ##########################################################################
     $DirectoryToSaveTo = "\\directory\" + $folder + "\" + $toPath
     $pdfName = $DirectoryToSaveTo  + $toDocName + ".pdf"
     $docName = $DirectoryToSaveTo + $toDocName + ".docx"
     write-log "Document Path: $DirectoryToSaveTo"
     write-log "PDF path: $pdfName"
     write-log "DOC path: $docName"

     ##########################################################################
     ##                                                                      ##
     ##  This section creates the document for the current firm.             ##   
     ##  saved ($DirectoryToSaveTo), as well as the formatting for the  PDF  ##
     ##  and DOCX file names ($pdfName and $docName).                        ##
     ##                                                                      ##
     ##########################################################################
     # create a folder for the current process (\$toName) if it doesn't exist
     if (!(Test-Path -path "$DirectoryToSaveTo")) {
       New-Item "$DirectoryToSaveTo" -type directory | out-null
        write-all "Created new directory $DirectoryToSaveTo"
     }
     #delete the TO document if it already exists
     else { 
       if (test-path $pdfName) { 
          rm $pdfName 
          write-all "Deleted previous version of PDF file ($pdfName)"}
       if (test-path $docName) { 
          rm $docName 
          write-all "Deleted previous version of DOC file ($docName)"}
     }

     [ref]$SaveFormat = "microsoft.office.interop.word.WdSaveFormat" -as [type] 
     $Word = New-Object -Com Word.Application    
     $Word.Visible = $false #set this to true for debugging
     write-log "Using Master File: $toTemplate"
     $Doc = $Word.Documents.Open($toTemplate, $false, $true) 

     write-log "Search & replace beginning for $firm"
     replaceText "CONTACT" $contact | out-null
     replaceText "DATE"    $TODAY   | out-null
     replaceText "TONAME"  $TOname  | out-null
     replaceText "R3" "R$([Char] 0x00B3)"  | out-null
     replaceText "S3" "S$([Char] 0xB3)"  | out-null
     write-log "Search & replace is complete for $firm"

     if ($row.cc1 -ne [DBNull]::Value) {
          $cc1 = $row.cc1 + "`r`t"
          replaceText "CC1 " $cc1 | out-null
     }
     else {
        replaceText "CC1 " "" | out-null
     }

     if ($row.cc2 -ne [DBNull]::Value) {
          $cc2 = $row.cc2 + "`r`t"
          replaceText "CC2 " $cc2 | out-null
     }
     else {
        replaceText "CC2 " "" | out-null
     }

     if ($row.cc3 -ne [DBNull]::Value) {
          $cc3 = $row.cc3 + "`r`t"
          replaceText "CC3 " $cc3 | out-null
     }
     else {
        replaceText "CC3 " "" | out-null
     }

     if ($row.cc4 -ne [DBNull]::Value) {
          $cc4 = $row.cc4 + "`r`t"
          replaceText "CC4 " $cc4 | out-null
     }
     else {
        replaceText "CC4 " "" | out-null
     }

     #$doc.SaveAs([ref]$docName,  [ref]$SaveFormat::wdFormatDocumentDefault) #http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238158%28v=office.12%29.aspx
     $doc.SaveAs([ref]$docName, [ref]16) #http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb238158%28v=office.12%29.aspx
     write-log "Merged Word doc for $firm has been saved at $docName."
     $doc.close()
     #$word.Quit([ref]0)
     $word.Quit()
     [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($word) | out-null
     [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($doc) | out-null

     $wordPDF = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
     $savePDF = $wordPDF.Documents.Open($docName, $false, $false)
     #$savePDF.SaveAs([ref]$pdfName, [ref]17)
     $savePDF.exportAsFixedFormat($pdfname, 17) 
     write-log "Merged Word doc for $firm has been saved at $pdfName."
     $savePDF.Close()
     $wordPDF.Quit()
     #$wordPDF.Quit([ref]0)
     [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($wordPDF)  | out-null
     [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::FinalReleaseComObject($savePDF)  | out-null
     [gc]::collect() 
     [gc]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()`
```

Comment: Why the [ref] in the passed filename and format? From the exception, you didn't release something; it clearly thinks you are still at it (the [refs]?)

Comment: @MickyBalladelli - Sorry for the delayed response. Without the [ref]s, I receive this error message: `
Argument: '1' should be a System.Management.Automation.PSReference. Use [ref].
At A:\yadayada.ps1:329 char:21
+          $doc.SaveAs <<<< ($docName, $SaveFormat::wdFormatDocumentDefault) #http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb2381
58%28v=office.12%29.aspx
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NonRefArgumentToRefParameterMsg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to work for me.

I removed the [ref]s and called `Quit()` without parameters.

```
 $pdfname = "d:\scripts\word.pdf"
 $docName = "d:\scripts\word.docx"
 $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
 $word.Visible = $true
 $doc = $word.Documents.Open($docName, $false, $false)
 $doc.SaveAs($docName,  16) 
 $doc.close()
 $word.Quit()

 $wordPDF = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
 $wordPDF.Visible = $true
 $savePDF = $wordPDF.Documents.Open($docName, $false, $false)

 $savePDF.exportAsFixedFormat($pdfname, 17)
```

I used `$word.Visible = $true` just to see what was going on, but you can remove it.

Comment: It still throws an error if I remove [ref] in front of the SaveAs variables. And once I add the [refs] I still get the "This file is in use by another application or user." message. It's maddening! This utility worked fine until about a month ago. I was using SaveAs instead of ExportAsFixedFormat, but then SaveAs stopped working suddenly.

Comment: Maybe we don't have parts of the code that will help reproduce it. I tried adding missing code, but I cannot reproduce as of now.

Comment: Thanks, Micky. I added the entire chunk of code I'm working with. I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you create a new script and copy/paste the code in the proposed solution, just so that we can verify that the issue is not from this code, but elsewhere? Use a local temp file for the WORD and PDF target files.

Comment: OK, yes we might have different versions of something which could explain the [ref] behavior. Concerning saving to a file: I was thinking about the location because I saw it was on the network somewhere. As a temporary fix, you could save locally and copy the saved file to the network location.

Comment: Micky - your code required that I add [ref] to the doc.SaveAs arguments. However, it got me thinking and I tried using my code to save the PDF doc on my local machine, which I could do with no problem. Saving the PDF to a network drive (where the Word doc is also located) seemed to be causing the exportasfixedformat/"file in use" error, so I updated the code to save the file to temp, then copy to remote directory. Thank you so much for your help!